# Некорректное поведение ячейки при удалении из UITableView в iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

Есть таблица, в ней ячейка с картинкой:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ISHPictureTVC *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailPicture" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.pictureView.image = picture;
    return cell;
}
```

Ячейка оформлена в storyboard, содержимае ячейки привязано к границам.
Размер ячейки высчитывается в:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CGFloat ratio = picture.size.height / picture.size.width; 
     CGFloat size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * ratio;
     return size;
}
```

При удалении ячейки свайпом:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        picture = nil;

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

В iOS 8.1 анимация удаления проигрывается корректно, а в iOS 7.1.2 (про другие версии не знаю) на устройстве и в симуляторе анимация выполняется некорректно.
Красная кнопка "Удалить" во время сжатия удаляемой строки остаётся неизменной.

iOS7 [image]

iOS8 [image]

Плюс ко всему изображение видно, если мало строк в таблице.

Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка "Удалить" сжималась на iOS 7?
Собственно тот же вопрос к содержимому ячейки.

Comment: У вас высота строк динамическая?

Comment: @Bimawa Если вы про UITableViewAutomaticDimension, то нет.
Высота строк высчитывается в методе heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @Zatoichy Я как раз про `heightForRowAtIndexPath` вы как высчитываете высоту строки? Не используете случаем данные из автолайаутов самой селки?

Comment: Просто, после внедрения поддержики автолайаутов в таблицах перекурочили много логики, из-за чего даже Apple приложения, буд-то записная кника и прочее содержащее таблицы, в ios8 поплыло. Совместить одинаковую работу в ios7 и ios8 не возможно без проверки OS так как придется прекрыть обработку некоторых методов.http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/887325

Comment: @Bimawa Спасибо, буду изучать.